# Переопределение цвета CheckBox - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox

Возникла проблема с программным переопределением цвета рамки CheckBox'а в отключенном состоянии.

По умолчанию цвет черный. Нужно просто поменять цвет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте кастомный `checkbox`. Кода под рукой нет, в ответ не оформлю, но посмотрите в эту сторону. Надо то: два png, один `xml` и атрибут в сам `checkbox` (не помню как называется :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать стиль

```
<style name="СheckBoxStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">CHECKEDCOLOR</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">UNCHECKEDCOLOR</item>
</style>
```

и применить его в качестве темы для Вашего чекбокса.

```
<CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/CheckBoxStyle"/>
```